# Why is RDS Postgres much slower than Postgres on EC2?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

Even if EC2 is running with `m7g.xlarge` and RDS is running `m7g.4xlarge` (twice CPU and memory)
I spent a lot of time tuning RDS, but still could not make it faster. I tried to make all configurations the same (same version of Postgres) and stopped RDS backup and replication. The RDS performance is still only half as fast as EC2. I am running on the same database setup, the same table with the same amount and data, and the same SQL query. I can understand 10% to 20% slower because of RDS overhead, but twice slower is not what I can understand or accept.
Does anyone experience the same?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sometime it happens, I experienced this with PostgreSQL inside EC2 (very cheap, high performance than other one) versus AWS Aurora RDS for PostgreSQL 15.5 compatible serverless v2.

Checklist:

- Check your AZ (availability zone),
- Region.
- If you use RDS Aurora Serveless v2, check number of ACUs.
- etc.

Has many factor cause more money but performance still did not gain.

Comment: This question is about RDS, not Aurora.

Comment: At this time, Amazon Aurora is a sub-set of Amazon RDS. See breadcumb at https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/

Comment: I stand corrected. Some time ago those were two separate things.